# Can't add material to angular module

Tags: angular-material, angular9

I try to find how to add angular material to work with angular divided into modules. It's work only in root, but not in modules.

```
ng add @angular/material
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/material": "^9.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.0-rc.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.0-rc.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~9.1.0-rc.1",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
```

home.module.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '../../../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HomeRoutingModule } from './home-routing.module';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HomeRoutingModule,
    MatCardModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

and my home.component.html

```
<p>home works!</p>
<mat-card>Simple card</mat-card>
```

it give me error:

> ```
> ERROR in src/app/home/home/home.component.html:2:1 - error NG8001: 'mat-card' is not a known element:
> 1. If 'mat-card' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'mat-card' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
> ```
>
> to suppress this message.

I tried to import material card module to app.module.ts. But then it's works only in root component, not in module.